# Number of zeroes on left hand plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying one of the past qualifying exam questions.

How many zeroes does the function $z^8 + \exp(2016 \pi z)$ have in the region where $\operatorname{Re}(z) < 0$.

I know I should use the argument principle here to solve it. But I still don't know how to solve it.

Comment: It has no zeros on $\Re(z) \le 0,|z| > 1$

Comment: Well, this is one insightful look at this problem. Then what should we do? count the net change of angle along the curve?

Comment: Yes, you can plot the increase of arg on $[-i,i]$ and $e^{it},t\in [\pi/2,3\pi/2]$, I find $20$ 'z= [i*[-1:0.01:1],exp(i*[pi/2:0.01:3*pi/2])]; plot(unwrap(angle(z.^8+exp(2016*pi*z)))/(2*pi));` https://octave-online.net/

Comment: Is it possible to count the change without the help of a computer? I am supposed to write out the solution without a computer's help.

Comment: In fact, I remember the professor once mentioned this in the class and the answer should be 2020. But I can not remember the proof details.

Comment: As you see 0.01 wasn't enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(z)$ be your function.  If $\operatorname{Re}(z) < 0$ and $\lvert z \rvert \geq 1$ then $\lvert z^8 \rvert > \lvert \exp(2016 \pi z) \rvert$ and so $f(z) \neq 0$.

If $z \in (-\mathrm i, \mathrm i)$ then $\lvert z^8 \rvert < \lvert \exp(2016 \pi z) \rvert$. This together with $f(\mathrm i)=f(-\mathrm i)=2$ shows that there are also no zeroes on the segment $[-\mathrm  i, \mathrm i]$.

The image of the interval $[-\mathrm i, \mathrm i]$ winds around the origin $2016$ times (the $\exp$ part is dominant there). The image of the left half circle from $\mathrm i$ back to $-\mathrm i$ winds around the origin four times ($z^8$ is dominant there). So in total the image of the contour winds around the origin $2020$ times. This is therefore the number of zeroes of $f$ in the left half-plane.

Comment: Can you explain how do you determine which part is dominant in different parts?

Comment: That just means the inequalities of the modulus as stated in the answer.